# Traffic manager with end point for Web app slot

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-traffic-manager

I was creating a Traffic Manager profile with end points for Dev and QA slots for Web Apps and wondered that is it not possible?

How can I create Traffic Manager endpoints for Dev and QA slots as we do it for production?

Answer (score 0):

Same way. Just select App Service Slot.

[image]

You can also use Powershell to enable TM for any external endpoint if portal interface does not allow you to do something you need.

[Azure Traffic Manager External Endpoints and Weighted Round Robin via PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/azure-traffic-manager-external-endpoints-and-weighted-round-robin-via-powershell/)

Comment: How to do using ARM cmdlets